# Cryptocurrency wallets

Tags: wallet, phantom-wallet, solana-pay

**What unique features distinguishes Phantom and Decaf wallets from other popular wallets? Phantom and Decaf wallets are like fancy digital wallets with cool extras that set them apart from others – think of them as feature-packed smartphones for your money!this is what I have found so far through ChatGPT but it does not give me these unique features **

Comment: Hello. I'll be closing this question as it is strictly opinion based on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each wallet is a bit different, best way to really see the difference is trying them for yourself. There are many wallets that are popular on solana for different types of users. Check out Solflare, Backpack, and Glow as well. See this page for a more comprehensive list of options: https://solana.com/ecosystem/explore?categories=wallet.